# How can I remove the glow when you click on a link?

Tags: android, html, css, safari, webkit

How can I remove the glow when you click on a link?
for Android 2.3, Safari/533.1
exapmle http://pic.lg.ua/l/VR6im/fTYa89/2

Comment: I tried :focus {outline:none}

Answer (score 3):

In your CSS:

> [-webkit-tap-highlight-color](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-tap-highlight-color): rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

Answer (score 2):

`a:active{outline: none;}` might be better

:focus is for when you tab to a link, as well as other instances.

When you click, the element has the pseudo-class, :active.